# How to validate a file name in java

Tags: java

I am working with a coverity issue which i need to validate a file name 
    using  regEx in java . In my application support .pdf , .txt , csv etc . My 
    file name getting as xxx.txt from user . i want to validate my file name 
    with proper extension format and not included any special character other 
    than dot ( eg .txt) .

```
filePath = properties.getProperty("DOCUMENT.LIBRARY.LOCATION");
String fileName = (String) request.getParameter("read");
```

Only If the file path is completed itsproper validation, the below code should be work .

```
filePath += "/" + fileName;
```

Comment: You can use regular expression. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [`String.endsWith()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#endsWith-java.lang.String-) method

```
if (fileName.endsWith(".pdf")) {
   // do something
}
```

Or use the method [`String.matches()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches-java.lang.String-)

```
fileName.matches("\\.(pdf|txt|csv)$")
```

Comment: As far as I am aware. String#matches() matches the entire thing, so you'd have to do `.+(pdf|txt|csv)`. Please correct me if I am wrong though.

Comment: `String#matches()` matches a regular expression, the regex I wrote matches any string with a `.` (dot character) one of the extensions in the list `(pdf|txt|csv)` and the dollar sign (`$`) with matches the end of the line. Have a look at this https://regex101.com/r/lHkU3N/1/

Comment: I was actually right, just went ahead and checked. You can have a look too, https://i.arsenarsen.com/dbgoy1wmui.png

Comment: [matches](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches-java.lang.String-) tells whether or not this string matches the given regular expression. A regex does not have to match strongly match the entire string.

Comment: @ArsenArsen The regex I wrote is made to validate a file name, that we suppose should be a string ending with a particular extension. That's what does the regex I wrote.

Comment: Actually, in the case of String#matches() it does. Try it for yourself. The image I posted is from a Scala REPL I ran. Keep in mind Scala is a JVM language, meaning the standard Java library applies.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145873/discussion-between-freedev-and-arsenarsen).

Answer (score 2):

This is a terrible answer as it only verifies the filename ends with the desired extension, but doesn't verify the rest of the filename as requested in the original question. Something more like this would be MUCH better:

```
fileName.matches("[-_. A-Za-z0-9]+\\.(pdf|txt|csv)");
```

This ensures the filename contains only ONE OR MORE -, _, PERIOD, SPACE, or alphanumeric characters, followed by exactly one of .pdf, .txt or .csv at the end of the filename. Your system might allow other characters in filenames and you could add them to this list if desired. An alternate, less secure approach is to prevent 'bad' characters something like:

```
fileName.matches("[^/\]+\\.(pdf|txt|csv)");
```

Which simply prevents / or \ characters from being in the file name before the required ending extension. But this doesn't prevent potentially other dangerous characters, like NULL bytes, for example.